# minted: Unicode characters in listing

Tags: unicode, minted

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines]{haskell}
--   `∀x. (id <$> x) ≅ x`
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Compiles well with:

```
xelatex --shell-escape ./haskell.tex
```

The symbols `∀` and `≅` are missing in the output file.

Comment: You might check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458627/how-do-i-display-unicode-characters-with-minted too, I used DeclareUnicodeCharacter instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a font which has the glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines]{haskell}
--   `∀x. (id <$> x) ≅ x`
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Davislor the OP used xelatex and minted is a verbatim environment, so no 8bit fonts were involved even without fontspec.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood you. The `\setmonofont` to one that contains the symbols is necessary for your answer to work, right?

Comment: @Davislor yes, as the default Latin modern mono open type font hasn't the glyphs. I'm exchanging unicode fonts, I'm  not switching from 8bit to unicode.

Comment: Testing the original snippet with `pdffonts`, I see that you are correct.